# Printing String from a char array?

Tags: arrays, string, char

Currently the code should replace all spaces in a string with %20. For the most part, I think the logic is right on the method I make a call to, but when I want to see the returned result I my main method prints nothing -- it prints a blank for the string. Could someone direct me where my my logic in turning the array into a string is incorrect? Thanks for the time and help. I attached my code for the method in case you guys needed it. Sorry if the mistake is dumb.

```
public class replaceSpaces {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] data = checkfor20("yo o");
    String text = String.valueOf(data); //turn char array into string representation 
    System.out.println(" new one: " + text); 
}

private static char[] checkfor20(String string) {
    int check = string.length(); //length of string 
    int spaceCount = 0, newLength;  //count spaces and new length with %20 put in 
    char[] charstring = string.toCharArray(); // turn string into char array 
    for(int i = 0; i < check ; i++) { //get space count for newlenght
        if (charstring[i] == ' ') {
            spaceCount++; 
    }
}
    newLength = check + (spaceCount * 2);
    char[] newArray = new char[newLength]; 
    for(int i = check - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(newArray[i] == ' ') { //get spaces and put it
            newArray[newLength - 1 ] = '0'; 
            newArray[newLength - 2 ] = '2'; 
            newArray[newLength - 3 ] = '%';
            newLength = newLength - 3; 
        }
        else { 
            newArray[newLength - 1] = charstring[i]; 
            newLength = newLength -  1; 

        }

    }
    return newArray; //return the new char array 

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not `newstring = oldstring.replace(" ","%20");`?

Answer (score 0):

Apologizes for the mistake on my part I was supposed to just change my array into

```
if(charstring[i] == ' ')
```

rather than the new array I created.